# Spring Boot Kafka Junit with application defined kafka server from docker compose

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, docker-compose, spring-kafka-test

I have Spring Boot Application with `docker-compose`,from it I am configuring `kafka` and other required application.

I have `Kafka` Producer and Consumer (`@kafkaListener`) in my application. I have `Kafka` and JPA Repository configuration from `@Bean` (not from `application.yml` file).

I am writing a junit test for `kafka` producer and consumer, but I want to use application defined `kafka` (defined in `docker-compose`).

So in my `pom.xml` I have `exec` goal, in which first start the application, then run the test collect report and last stop the application.

Can someone please help me to write Junit for kafka producer and consumer by using application defined kafka. I tried `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class), @SpringBootTest, @EmbeddedKafka` but always I am getting exception.

```
  <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Create IT environment</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>${basedir}/start-services.sh</executable>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>Generate Cobertura Reports</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>${skip.coverage}</skip>
                        <executable>${basedir}/coverage/report.sh</executable>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>Clean up environment</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>${basedir}/stop-services.sh</executable>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Sample Test -

```
 @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
 @SpringBootTest
 @EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, brokerProperties = {  "listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092", "port=9092" })
 public class KafkaProcessorITCase {

    private static final String TOPIC = "topic";

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private MessageConsumer consumer;

    @Autowired
    private MessageProducer producer;

    @Test
    public void shouldProcessMessage() throws  Exception {

        String message = "Sample message";

        producer.sendMessage(message, TOPIC);
        
        //Assertions
 }
}
```

Producer Config

```
  @Bean
  public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerConfig() {
     Map<String, Object> configMap = new HashMap<>();
     configMap.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,      System.getenv("KAFKA_BROKERS"));
     configMap.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, producerAcks);
     configMap.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, retries);
     configMap.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,    StringSerializer.class.getName());
     configMap.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);

     return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configMap);
  }
```

ERROR :

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.cloud.configuration.CompositeCompatibilityVerifier.verifyDependencies(CompositeCompatibilityVerifier.java:47)
at org.springframework.cloud.configuration.CompatibilityVerifierAutoConfiguration.compositeCompatibilityVerifier(CompatibilityVerifierAutoConfiguration.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:123)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:208)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:158)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:86)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:95)
```

Comment: Please share the source code of your test case and the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Hi roccobaroccoSC, I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
The exception you are getting means that Spring cannot find providers for all the objects annotated with @Autowired. You need to make sure that all autowired objects can be instantiated by a provider method or a bean.

I am by no means a Kafka expert, but looking at [this post](https://question-it.com/questions/523798/embeddedkafka-ne-rabotaet-vyzyvaet-oshibku-scala) (sorry, it's only in Russian but take a look at the code anyway), they have a bean for the KafkaTemplate and you used it differently. See their code:

```java
    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Greeting> greetingKafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(greetingProducerFactory());
    }
```

and then they annotated it as @Autowired in KafkaProducer.

Do you have providers for the following variables?

```java
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private MessageConsumer consumer;

    @Autowired
    private MessageProducer producer;
```

By the way, you could look into using [Mockito](https://www.baeldung.com/injecting-mocks-in-spring) for consumer and producer. I don't know if this works for Kafka though.

Comment: Hi roccobaroccoSC, Sorry for the confusion. I have updated the question with error i am getting. when do `mvn claen verify`

Comment: It's ok, I will edit my answer.

Comment: I edited the answer, please take a look.

Comment: I am doing everything same as mentioned in link but facing same issue. I am not sure why `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory` giving `NullPointer`

Comment: I thought we were past that point. Your current exception stack relates to Spring not being able to load ApplicationContext. The NullPointerException is not relevant anymore, is it?